# Why this long return statement is not working in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, compare

I have a JSON object with the next structure:

```js
{
    "matters": [
        {
            "title": "Systems",
            "date": "23/08/2010",
            "score": 5
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

I want to sort this data with the `sort()` function. I can do it by using the `score` field, but I can't sort it using the `date` field. This is what I'm currently using:

```js
$.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {
    // data now contains one node with all the matters
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        // val now contains one matter per nodes
        val.sort(function (a,b) {
            return
            parseInt(a.date.substring(6,10)+a.date.substring(3,5)+a.date.substring(0,2)) -
            parseInt(b.date.substring(6,10)+b.date.substring(3,5)+b.date.substring(0,2));
        });
        // Here I get the same array not sorted!
    }
});
```

Both `parseInt()` functions returns an integer with this format:

```
if date=="23/08/2010" => 20100823
```

I used alerts to check if I'm splitting correctly the date and it is fine. Anyway, I can not sort the array.

I'm testing the code using [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6001221/) JSON file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post an example of two dates that sort incorrectly? Or is the array simply not sorted at all?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nEPTt/

Comment: @CrazyTrain You are right. It is working perfectly there. How can be possible that I have exactly the same code on my *localhost* and it is not working??!

Comment: Not sure. You're sure the code is *completely* identical? And FWIW, I'd do `+a.date.split("/").reverse().join("")` to process the date. A little cleaner. I'd also probably store the processed date on the object so the same dates don't need to keep being processed. http://jsfiddle.net/Pcanx/

Comment: The only difference really is that he isn't loading a JSON file with $.getJSON. Have you tried doing a console.log(data) within the function to see if you actually get the JSON object?

Comment: I wonder if there's some whitespace padding around your dates, or something like that. I don't really want to post an answer unless I know why it fixed it. You can go ahead and post the code in an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I tested the code thousands of times. This is my last test, and it shows that I don't have any difference in the source of the data: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6004779/ I tried copying your code (**cop & past**) and I still get the same results! It is insane. Please, write an answer, because your line have worked, and I don't know what it is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look closer at my code, you will note that the `return` has a break line and *then* are both `parseInt()` functions.

There was the error. The function wasn't returning the correct values. The solution is just remove all the breacklines and leave all the `return` statement in *one line*.

**Bad code:**

```
return
parseInt(a.date.substring(6,10)+a.date.substring(3,5)+a.date.substring(0,2)) -
parseInt(b.date.substring(6,10)+b.date.substring(3,5)+b.date.substring(0,2));
```

**Code working:**

```
return parseInt(a.date.substring(6,10)+a.date.substring(3,5)+a.date.substring(0,2)) - parseInt(b.date.substring(6,10)+b.date.substring(3,5)+b.date.substring(0,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how I implemented the sorting. I didn't use your JSON file, but it should be possible for you to get the idea:

```
var data = {
    "matters": [{
        "title": "Sistema de Procesamiento de Datos",
            "date": "03/08/2011",
            "score": 8
    }, {
        "title": "Programación I",
            "date": "30/07/2010",
            "score": 7
    }, {
        "title": "Elementos de Investigación Operativa",
            "date": "07/08/2003",
            "score": 10
    }, {
        "title": "Programación III",
            "date": "05/08/2009",
            "score": 10
    }, {
        "title": "Laboratorio de Computación III",
            "date": "05/08/2010",
            "score": 10
    }]
};

$.each(data, function(key, val) {

    val.sort(function (a, b) {
        function date_to_int(d) {
            var parts = d.split('/');
            var day = parts[0];
            var month = parts[1];
            var year = parts[2];
            day = (day.length < 2) ? '0' + day : day;
            month = (month.length < 2) ? '0' + month : month;
            year = (year.length < 3) ? '20' + year : year;
            return year + month + day;
        }
        return date_to_int(a.date) - date_to_int(b.date);
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/bjarkehs/TJNE6/2/

Comment: Sorry, I misread the result. But ultimately you're not doing anything substantially different from OP. You just refactored the code.

Comment: That's true. I'm not able to decode his problem from what he's writing however. I figured maybe he was having some issues with the sorting performing weirdly. I saw your comment on how you suggested handling the comparison instead, and I quite like that idea. I think the issue might simply be with loading the JSON file.